# Can Sombody help to insert my data in database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
#This one is my old working insert
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(
    "INSERT INTO room.save(
        exacttime,
        depletion_time, 
        expected_dip_time
    ) values (
        '" & lblexact.Text & "',
        '" & Trim(TextBox6.Text) & "', 
        Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second))
    ", con)
```

This is my problem, I just add one data expected_dip_time2 and one value. I think have error with comma or any symbols here. because I tried in MySQL and it also working.

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(
    "INSERT INTO room.save(
        exacttime, 
        depletion_time, 
        expected_dip_time, 
        expected_dip_time2
    ) values (
        '" & lblexact.Text & "',
        '" & Trim(TextBox6.Text) & "', 
        Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second)) " & ",
        DATE_SUB(Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second), interval 1 hour)
    ", con)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second query:

```
... depletion_time day_second)) " & ", ...
                              ^
```

you have too many closing parentheses after the `day_second`. It's closing off both the `date_add` function *and* the `values` section.

You should have *one* `)` at that point and *two* following the `interval 1 hour` of the `date_sub`.

In other words, something like:

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(
    "INSERT INTO room.save(" &
         "exacttime,depletion_time,expected_dip_time,expected_dip_time2" &
    ") values ('" &
        lblexact.Text &
        "','" & Trim(TextBox6.Text) &
        "',Date_add(exacttime,interval depletion_time day_second)" &
        ",DATE_SUB(Date_add(exacttime,interval depletion_time day_second)," &
            "interval 1 hour))"
    , con)
```